# Lilypond: \downbow and \upbow don't show up in 2nd staff tablature

Tags: lilypond, tablature

In one StaffGroup I'm trying to write one staff in note notation with a TabStaff below in which ^\downbow and ^\upbow are used. However, these markups don't show up in the end result. Why is that and how to get the desired result?

```
\new StaffGroup <<
        \new Voice {
          a'^\markup "a" b' c'' d'' 
        }
        \new TabStaff {
          \new TabVoice {
            a^\downbow b^\upbow c'^\downbow d'^\upbow
          }
        }
      >>
```

[image: Tab_no_up-_and_downbow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While @Lazy's answer is perfectly correct, I would like to point out the `\tabFullNotation` command (used as `\new TabSaff { \new TabVoice { \tabFullNotation ... } }`), which prints a fuller form of tablature including scripts among other items like stems.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Tabstaff does not show a lot of stuff by default. To revert this do

```
\revert TabStaff.Script.stencil
```

before somewhere before the downbows. To remove them again do `\override Script.stencil = ##f` or `\omit Script`.

If you want to know what TabStaff does do in detail, checkout the section

```
\context {
  \Staff
  \alias Staff
  \name TabStaff
  ...
}
```

in engraver-init.ly